# How to Save Different Usermeta Fields According to User Role?

Tags: customization, users, profiles

I have created some custom roles using a plugin and I have also created custom user meta fields that are show in the Profile pages of each user (/wp-admin/profile.php)

I have a problem with saving the custom fields, I can save the fields ok if I don't change the users' role. So, to give an example:

- User 1 has fields a, b, and c and they have a user role of Pending.
- If I change their user role to Owner, the fields they have are a and
  b
- If I then change their user role to Pending the details that were in field C disappear

It seems that WP is removing it from the database. I want to be able to change the roles and fields without losing the data that is stored in the usermeta database table.

I think my problem is with the update_usermeta function.

```
//saving the user fields
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );

function save_user_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'unit_type', $_POST['unit_type'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'registered_as', $_POST['registered_as'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'date_registered', $_POST['date_registered'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'unit_number', $_POST['unit_number'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'owner1_address', $_POST['owner1_address'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'owner1_tel_day', $_POST['owner1_tel_day'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'owner1_tel_night', $_POST['owner1_tel_night'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'emergency_contact_name', $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'emergency_contact_tel_day',     $_POST['emergency_contact_tel_day'] );
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'emergency_contact_tel_night',     $_POST['emergency_contact_tel_night'] );
}
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing your actual code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Observation: following the guidelines [suggested in this article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), I'm trying to improve the quality both of the Q and the A. It's a learning process...

In your [original code](http://pastebin.com/pFHCfRsh), you were displaying different input fields according to the user role and other conditionals.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'user_fields_for_admin', 10);
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'user_fields_for_admin', 10);
function user_fields_for_admin( $user ){ 
    switch ($user->roles[0]) {
        case 'pending':
            if ($selected_register == "Owner"){
                // Display some fields;
            } elseif ($selected_register == "Board") {
                // Display other fields
            }
            break;

        case 'owner':
            // Display yet another fields
            break;
    }
}
```

But when saving the fields using `update_usermeta` (as per the code in your edited question), all the fields were being saved, regardless if they were being displayed or not.

You have to check if the field value is being passed, so the usermeta will not be overridden with non-existent values at each and every update.

```
function save_user_fields($user_id) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
        return false;
    if( isset($_POST['unit_type']) )     update_usermeta($user_id, 'unit_type', $_POST['unit_type']);
    if( isset($_POST['registered_as']) ) update_usermeta($user_id, 'registered_as', $_POST['registered_as']);
    // ETC
}
```

---

### Suggestions for debug and printing Html

For your reference, you can check the contents of a PHP object using this code:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($user, true).'</pre>';
```

And instead of echoing one line at the time, you can use the [Heredoc sintax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for easy reading/printing Html. PHP variables goes inside curly brackets. Example:

```
echo <<<HTML
    <h3>Owner Details</h3>
    <table class="form-table"><tbody><tr>
    <tr><th>First Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name1" value="{$first_name}" class="regular-text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Last Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name1" value="{$last_name}" class="regular-text" /></td>
    </tr>
HTML;
```

Comment: The saving bit is now working like a charm. Much appreciated on that. i don't fully understand your first but about there not being an owners role. I have added custom roles to WP hence checking for 'owner'

Comment: @Fraggy - oh, I see... As I didn't create the roles for testing I thought it was a bug. But did you manage to make the whole thing work?

Comment: Yes I did manage to make it all work, thanks @brasofilo. Do you want me to remove my answer and accept yours? I didn't realise I was doing it wrongly, sorry!

Comment: @Fraggy - IMO, your answer would not be redundant if you were adding new information to it. I think my answer is over-explained, but in the code you posted it was not clear that `Owner` is considered a *Role* **and** a *custom usermeta*. IMO (again), this Q&A would be more useful if we did little edits to both the Q and the A. So, before doing that, the problem in your code was only with `update_usermeta`?

Comment: Ok I will reword it all and make better sense of it and we can take it from there. Thanks again!

Comment: I have reworded my question big time to make a lot more sense of it. I think that you just need to keep the code of the usermeta function only in your answer. Then we are all good to go and I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Fraggy - I've put some context in my answer exposing the motivations and full scope of the problem. I guess we both learned a little bit on making better Q&A, cheers!

Comment: thanks, that all looks great now. It's all a learning curve!